# How to modify Angular Material date range picker to accept only months

Tags: angular, angular-material

Since version 10, Angular Material offers a date range picker. Does someone know how to modify this component to select a month range? My current solution is to allow only the first day of each month, but it would be awesome if I can pick the range from the year view.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoZrJ.png

See https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?